# javascript: escape html, and convert plain text links to <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I'm using the underscore js method of escaping HTML:

```
var __entityMap = {
"&": "&amp;",
"<": "&lt;",
">": "&gt;",
'"': '&quot;',
"'": '&#39;',
"/": '&#x2F;'
};

String.prototype.escapeHTML = function() {
return String(this).replace(/[&<>"'\/]/g, function(s) {
    return __entityMap[s];
});
}
```

The problem is that this also escapes "/" and this makes my auto linker no longer work.

I'm using:

https://github.com/bryanwoods/autolink-js/blob/master/autolink.js

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: I don't see why `/` needs to be escaped in the first place?  Just remove it from `__entityMap` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments -- there's no reason to escape a single forward slash -- you should experience no issue just removing it from the list of characters you're escaping. You only need to escape characters which would break your code if left intact, and the forward slash is unlikely to cause any issues left as it is.

[OWASP does recommend](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) escaping forward slashes, which may be why you were at some point recommended to do that -- but that recommendation is for loading content **from untrusted sources**. If you're loading your own template that you wrote, you don't have to worry that you're going to run a cross-site scripting attack on yourself.

Comment: I do load from untrusted sources.

Comment: I'm not convinced - their reasoning, *"the forward slash is included as it helps to end an HTML entity"* is not a strong argument (unless I'm missing something there is no other citation?).  If we take a step back... the root problem, **escaping html** only *really* requires that you escape `<` `>` `&` - the quotes won't do any harm but it all depends on the context in which you are embedding the resultant string.  To my mind the forward slash though is completely unnecessary and suggesting escaping it only serves break 3rd party libraries not expecting it and/or pollute the web in general.

Comment: Yeah, I'm inclined to say that since it's only dangerous in combination with other characters that you're already escaping, it's not worth finding some convoluted workaround -- just make an exception to the recommended list in this case since you know you're covered by the fact that you're escaping the `<` and `>`.